# Python not jumping into "else" condition

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

Good morning,

This is my 1st post here & Im only dabbing my feet in programming pool so please be gentle :)

As it currently stands, I have to fulfill 2 conditions (sadcat & great == yes). What I want instead is to jump straight to else ( 'Why did you even start this game in the first place? This is a rhetorical question btw.'), if the 1st condition is not ulfilled (sadcat == something else than 'yes')
I have no idea why doesnt this work... Indentation seems to be OK to me. Any help is appreciated

```
sadcat = input('Do you like war? ')
great = input ('That\'s great but are you also a cat? ')


if sadcat == 'yes':
    if great == 'yes':
      print('ok I have no more questions')
    else:
      print('Not a cat ? How do you even live with yourself.')
else:
  print('Why did you even start this game in the first place? This is a rhetorical question btw.', end=" ")
```

Comment: its working as you explained.

Comment: it seems to be working fine, what input did you try and what output do you expect?

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine, if I've understood your question correctly. Can you provide example of input and output in question please?

Comment: If sadcat equals something else than 'yes' I want it to jump straight into this line: print('Why did you even start this game in the first place? This is a rhetorical question btw.', end=" ")

It doesnt do it though, it goes into "great" variable even if I type something else than "yes" in input

I hope Im explaining it well

Comment: You'd like to avoid asking the second question, am I right?

Comment: Then you should ask it after the first if

Comment: @JackLilhammers Precisely! I want to it avoid asking the 2nd question if the 1st condition is not fulfilled

Comment: Then move the second `input` line into the if block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the "game" to end if the "player" doesn't like war, then the first if should be right after the first question

```
sadcat = input('Do you like war? ')
if sadcat == 'no':
    print('Why did you even start this game in the first place? This is a rhetorical question btw.', end=" ")
    exit()

great = input ('That\'s great but are you also a cat? ')
if great == 'yes':
    print('ok I have no more questions')
else:
    print('Not a cat ? How do you even live with yourself.')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So basically I cannot place one IF after another (because both conditions will be interpreted one after another), I have to separate those in different blocks of code. Makes sense now.

Comment: Of course you can! I just avoid nesting blocks, because it's more readable to me

Comment: You can do as @khelwood suggested and you have you don't have to separate the blocks

Comment: Gotcha. But If I do nesting blocks (like I did in the original code - one IF after another IF) then interpreter will go line by line & I will not receive the desired output

Your code is certainly easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

so basically code works with it executing each line in the order it is written.
in your code it first takes input for sadcat, then input for great.

only after that it starts evaluating sadcat.
(your code is correct. once it gets to the evaluating part, it will go straight to the else)

if you wish the game to end right after the person types anything other than 'yes'

```
import sys

sadcat = input('Do you like war? ')
if sadcat != 'yes':
    print('Why did you even start this game in the first place? This is a rhetorical question btw.', end=" ")
    sys.exit() #this will terminate the program    

great = input ('That\'s great but are you also a cat? ')


if sadcat == 'yes':
    if great == 'yes':
      print('ok I have no more questions')
    else:
      print('Not a cat ? How do you even live with yourself.')
```

Comment: Thank you, similar to Jack Lilhammers solution :)